# Eliminar numeros repetidos en un arreglo dinamico en C

Tags: array, c, punteros, estructuras, repetidos

Si bien parece que no es un tema que no se haya hablado me encuentro con una situación particular que me gustaría me ayuden a saber por que ocurre.

La situación es que tengo un arreglo dinámico de números aleatorios los cuales pueden ser repetidos, si son repetidos debo pasarlo a otro vector dinámico (la longitud de este vector cambia en tiempo de ejecución y pensaba hacerlo con `realloc`), la particularidad es que necesito hacerlo con punteros y estructuras y no comprendo por qué hay un `if` en el que no esta entrado por mas que estoy viendo que cumple la condición con un `if`.

Otro error que no se por qué ocurre es cuando quiero cambiar el tamaño nuevo del vector porque necesito que el vector que no contenga repetidos aumente en 1 su tamaño ya que estoy agregando un nuevo valor, proporciono el código que esta documentado, es un poco largo así que pongo solo las partes problemáticas y abajo dejo todo el código.

Brevemente la idea es que tenga un i que se quede parado en un valor del vector con repetidos (lo llamare vector 1) y compare con un j que se moverá por todo el vector sin repetidos (lo llamare vector 2) entonces si llega al final del j sin encontrar repetidos puedo hacer un `realloc` con el valor de i que encontré, de lo contrario si encontre el repetido salgo del `while` y voy al siguiente valor de i.

```
void sacar_repetidos(vector *a, vector2 *b)
{
  int i = 0;
  
  for (i = 0; i < a->size; i++)
  {
    int j = 0;
    while(j <= b->nuevo_size )
    {
      if(b->nuevo_size == 0) //no lo tengo que comprar con nada porque es el primero entonces lo aloco directamente
      {
        b->vec2 = malloc(1*sizeof(int));
        b->vec2[j] = a->vec[i];
        b->nuevo_size = 1; //este es el caso donde me obliga a poner el valor concreto, 1 pero no me deja escribir  b->nuevo_size = b->nuevo_size+  1; y no se por que
      }
      
      
      while (b-> vec2[j] != a->vec[i]  && j <= b->nuevo_size) //mientras el valor de vec2 sea distinto al vec y sea menos que el tamaño del vec2
      {
        printf(" %i",j); //imprimo para corroborar los valores de i y nuevo_size y veo que son los mismos efectivamente
        printf(" %i ",b-> nuevo_size);
        j++; 
        printf(" %i ",a->vec[i]);
        printf("\n");
        
      }
      if (b-> nuevo_size == j ) //este es el if al que deberia entrar pero no lo hace por mas que veo que alcanza los valores que le estoy pidiendo
        {
          printf("entra");
          b-> nuevo_size = b-> nuevo_size + 1;
          b ->vec2 = realloc(b-> vec2, b -> nuevo_size);
        }
        if (b-> vec2[j] == a->vec[i]) //encontre un repetido en esa posicion de j
        {
          break;
        }
      
    }
  }
}
```

También dejo el código completo de ser necesario, disculpen si esta mal escrito, aun estoy practicando

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


typedef struct
{
  int *vec;
  int size;
} vector;

typedef struct
{
  int *vec2;
  int nuevo_size;
}vector2;


void inicializar(vector *a, int tamaño_inicial) 
{
  a->vec = malloc(tamaño_inicial * sizeof(int));
  a->size = tamaño_inicial;
}



void llenar(vector *a)
{
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < a->size; i++)
  {
    a->vec[i] = rand()%10;
  }
}

void mostrar(vector *a)
{
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < a->size; i++)
  {
    printf(" %i ",a->vec[i]);
  }
}

void vaciar(vector *a)
{
  free(a->vec);

}

void sacar_repetidos(vector *a, vector2 *b)
{
  int i = 0;
  
  for (i = 0; i < a->size; i++)
  {
    int j = 0;
    while(j <= b->nuevo_size )
    {
      if(b->nuevo_size == 0) //no lo tengo que comprar con nada porque es el primero entonces lo aloco directamente
      {
        b->vec2 = malloc(1*sizeof(int));
        b->vec2[j] = a->vec[i];
        b->nuevo_size = 1; //este es el caso donde me obliga a poner el valor concreto, 1 pero no me deja escribir  b->nuevo_size = b->nuevo_size+  1; y no se por que
      }
      
      
      while (b-> vec2[j] != a->vec[i]  && j <= b->nuevo_size) //mientras el valor de vec2 sea distinto al vec y sea menos que el tamaño del vec2
      {
        printf(" %i",j); //imprimo para corroborar los valores de i y nuevo_size y veo que son los mismos efectivamente
        printf(" %i ",b-> nuevo_size);
        j++; 
        printf(" %i ",a->vec[i]);
        printf("\n");
        
      }
      if (b-> nuevo_size == j ) //este es el if al que deberia entrar pero no lo hace por mas que veo que alcanza los valores que le estoy pidiendo
        {
          printf("entra al if");
          b-> nuevo_size = b-> nuevo_size + 1;
          b ->vec2 = realloc(b-> vec2, b -> nuevo_size);
        }
        if (b-> vec2[j] == a->vec[i]) //encontre un repetido en esa posicion de j
        {
          break;
        }
      
    }
  }
}


void mostrar_sin_repetidos(vector2 *b)
{
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < b->nuevo_size; i++)
  {
    printf(" %i ",b->vec2[i]);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  vector v;
  vector2 nuevo;
  nuevo.nuevo_size = 0;
  inicializar(&v, 4);
  llenar(&v);
  printf("Vector original:");
  mostrar(&v);
  printf("\n");
  sacar_repetidos(&v, &nuevo);
  printf("Vector sin repetidos:");
  mostrar_sin_repetidos(&nuevo);
  printf("\n");
  printf("Tamaño del nuevo vector: ");
  printf("%i ",nuevo.nuevo_size);
  return 0;
}
```

Dejo una aclaración importante, si por algun motivo alguien quiere copiar y pegar el código para probar su funcionamiento o cualquier motivo probablemente tenga errores por el uso de la letra "ñ", solo fue usada en la función inicializar por lo que solo cambiándolo en ese lugar ¡ya debería funcionar para todos!

¡Gracias de antemano!

Edito: logre hacer funcionar mi código, para cualquiera que lo quisiese ver lo dejo a disposición.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct
{
  int *vec;
  int size;
} vector;




void inicializar(vector *vect, int tamaño_inicial) 
{
  vect->vec = malloc(tamaño_inicial * sizeof(int));
  vect->size = tamaño_inicial;
}



void llenar(vector *vect)
{
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < vect->size; i++)
  {
    vect->vec[i] = rand()%10;
  }
}

void mostrar(vector *vect)
{
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i <vect->size; i++)
  {
    printf(" %i ",vect->vec[i]);
  }
}

void vaciar(vector *vect)
{
  free(vect->vec);
  vect ->size = 0;
}


void add(vector *vect, int valor)
{
  int* ptr = (int*) realloc(vect->vec, vect->size + 30);
  vect->vec = ptr;
  vect->vec[vect->size++] = valor;
  
}

void sacar_repetidos(vector *original, vector *sin_repetidos)
{
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < original->size; i++)
  {
    int j = 0;
    int repetido = 0;
  
    for(j = 0; j < sin_repetidos->size && !repetido; j++) // gracias eferion por esta sintaxis
    {
      if (original->vec[i] == sin_repetidos->vec[j])
      {
        repetido = 1;
      }
    }
      if(!repetido)
      {
        add(sin_repetidos, original->vec[i]);  
      }

    
  }
}



int main(void) {
  srand(time(NULL));
  vector v;
  vector nuevo;
  inicializar(&v, 25);
  llenar(&v);
  printf("Vector original:");
  mostrar(&v);
  printf("\n");
  inicializar(&nuevo, 0);
  sacar_repetidos(&v, &nuevo);
  printf("\n");
  printf("Vector sin repetidos:");
  mostrar(&nuevo);
  printf("\n");
  printf("Tamaño del nuevo vector: ");
  printf(" %i ", nuevo.size);
  vaciar(&v);
  vaciar(&nuevo);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No me he parado a comprender a fondo tu problema, pero... ¿no será porque la condición del while antes de ese if debería ser  `j < b->nuevo_size` en lugar de `j <= b->nuevo_size` ?

Comment: Si, era uno de los problemas que tenia el codigo eso hacia que nunca entre en el if. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código es un baile desordenado de variables, índices y demás. Es complicado darte una respuesta concreta del motivo del fallo porque convergen varios problemas de diseño.

Un problema que tienes es que tu programa no genera realmente números aleatorios. No inicializas la semilla del generador de números aleatorios, luego siempre obtendrás exactamente los mismos resultados, sin importar cuántas veces ejecutes el programa.

Esto se soluciona con una simple línea de código:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Añadiendo esta línea antes del primer uso de `rand()` tendrá como efecto que tu programa empezará a generar secuencias diferentes en cada ejecución (salvo que consigas ejecutar el programa dos veces seguidas en el mismo segundo).

Por otro lado, variables con nombres como `a`, `b`, ... no aportan absolutamente nada. No ayudan a entender mejor el código y hacen que seas más propenso a equivocarte de variable. Acostúmbrate a usar nombres de variables que sean representativos.

Hablando del diseño de la aplicación, no hay ninguna necesidad de gestionar dos estructuras diferentes. Con un único `struct` te serviría:

```
typedef struct
{
  int *vec;
  int size;
} vector;
```

Pero quizás habría que añadir algo de información a esta estructura para poder usarla con más comodidad:

```
typedef struct
{
    int *vec;
    size_t size;
    size_t count;
} vector;
```

Con este cambio podemos saber cuántos elementos hay en la estructura.

Este diseño nos permite crear fácilmente un ecosistema de utilidades para trabajar cómodamente con la estructura:

```
// Inicializa un objeto de tipo vector
vector NewVector()
{
    vector vect;
    memset(&vect, 0, sizeof(vector));
    return vect;
}

// Libera la memoria asociada a un vector
void FreeVector(vector * vect)
{
    // Liberamos la memoria reservada
    free(vect->vec);

    // Reseteamos las variables de estado, para ser coherentes
    memset(vect, 0, sizeof(vector));
}

// Actualiza el vector para que sea capaz de almacenar un número de elementos dado
int SetCapacity(vector* vect, size_t capacity)
{
    if( capacity > vect->size )
    {
        int* ptr = (int*)realloc(vect->vec, vect->size + 10);
        if( ptr == NULL )
        {
            return 0; // Error, no hay memoria suficiente
        }
        vect->vec = ptr;
        vect->size = capacity;
    }

    return 1;
}

// Añade un nuevo elemento al final del vector (redimensiona el array si es necesario)
int Add(vector* vect, int value)
{
    if( vect->size == vect->count )
    {
        // Incrementamos la capacidad en 10 (es muy costoso hacer incrementos individuales)

        if( !SetCapacity(vect, vect->size + 10) )
        {
            return 0; // Error, no hay memoria
        }
    }

    vect->vec[vect->count++] = value;
    return 1;
}
```

Estas utilidades armonizan la forma de utilizar los vectores, ahora los dos se pueden usar exactamente igual, no hay necesidad de duplicar código en ningún sitio.

Ahora tu código se simplifica enormemente:

```
void llenar(vector *vect)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vect->size; i++)
    { 
        Add(vect, rand()%10);
    }
}

void mostrar(vector const* vect)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vect->count; i++)
    {
        printf("%i ",vect->vec[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    vector original = NewVector();
    vector nuevo    = NewVector();

    SetCapacity(&original, 4);

    srand(time(NULL));
    llenar(&original);

    printf("Vector original:");
    mostrar(&original);

    sacar_repetidos(&original, &nuevo);
    printf("Vector sin repetidos:");
    mostrar(&nuevo);

    printf("Tamaño del nuevo vector: %lu\n", nuevo.count);

    FreeVector(&original);
    FreeVector(&nuevo);

    return 0;
}
```

Para empezar, te estás ahorrando una función para imprimir el segundo tipo de vector (código duplicado), y aún no hemos empezado a actuar sobre la función importante de tu programa:

```
void sacar_repetidos(vector const* original, vector * sin_repetidos)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < original->count; i++)
    {
        int repetido = 0;
        for( size_t j=0; j<sin_repetidos->count && !repetido; j++)
        {
            repetido = original->vec[i] == sin_repetidos->vec[j];
        }
        
        if( !repetido )
        {
            Add(sin_repetidos, original->vec[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

La búsqueda de elementos repetidos no podría ser ahora más simple. Se recorre el array original y, para cada valor, se realiza una búsqueda en el array que no tiene duplicados. Si el número no se encuentra en este segundo array es porque es un número nuevo, lo añadimos a este vector y pasamos al siguiente número.

Puedes ver el código funcionando [aquí](https://onlinegdb.com/SJ2b0NtZO)

No me propuesto corregir tu código porque la implementación es un poco caótica. Hay veces en las que es preferible tirarlo todo y empezar de nuevo, lleva menos trabajo.

Así, por ejemplo, llamas a `malloc` dentro del bucle:

```
for (i = 0; i < a->size; i++)
{
  int j = 0;
  while(j <= b->nuevo_size )
  {
    if(b->nuevo_size == 0) //no lo tengo que comprar con nada porque es el primero entonces lo aloco directamente
    {
      b->vec2 = malloc(1*sizeof(int));
      b->vec2[j] = a->vec[i];
      b->nuevo_size = 1; //este es el caso donde me obliga a poner el valor concreto, 1 pero no me deja escribir  b->nuevo_size = b->nuevo_size+  1; y no se por que
    }
```

Ese código está claramente fuera de lugar. Es una creación incondicional, es decir, lo primero que haces al entrar en ese bucle es hacer una reserva para un primer elemento. Si es incondicional, ¿Por qué no hacer esta reserva fuera del bucle? Así el bucle sería más sencillo de revisar.

Bucles anidados:

```
while(j <= b->nuevo_size )
{
  // ...
  
  while (b-> vec2[j] != a->vec[i]  && j <= b->nuevo_size) //mientras el valor de vec2
```

Se supone que únicamente hay que recorrer el array `b` una vez por cada valor del array `a`. No hay necesidad de anidar dos bucles cuya misión, en teoría, es recorrer `b`.

Otro detalle, este tiene que ver con tu duda, **no**, el código no tiene por qué entrar en el `if`:

```
  while (b-> vec2[j] != a->vec[i]  && j <= b->nuevo_size) //mientras el valor de vec2 sea distinto al vec y sea menos que el tamaño del vec2
  {
    printf(" %i",j); //imprimo para corroborar los valores de i y nuevo_size y veo que son los mismos efectivamente
    printf(" %i ",b-> nuevo_size);
    j++; 
    printf(" %i ",a->vec[i]);
    printf("\n");
    
  }
  if (b-> nuevo_size == j ) //este es el if al que deberia entrar pero no lo hace por mas que veo que alcanza los valores que le estoy pidiendo
```

Fíjate en las condiciones del `while`. Tiene lo siguente: `j <= b->nuevo_size`. Por otro lado, el contenido del while incrementa `j`. El efecto que se puede conseguir es el siguiente:

- `j < b->nuevo_size` -> Se ejecuta el bucle, se incrementa `j`
- `j == b->nuevo_size` -> Se ejecuta el bucle, se incrementa `j`
- `j > b->nuevo_size` -> Se abandona el bucle, `j > b->nuevo_size`, tampoco entra en el `if`

Todo indica que la condición del `while` está mal escrita y debería ser así:

```
while (b-> vec2[j] != a->vec[i]  && j < b->nuevo_size)
//                                    ^ menor que en vez de menor o igual
```

Ahora bien, al corregir este problema el código entra en un bucle sin fin que termina abruptamente cuando el sistema no te deja reservar más memoria ... problemas derivados de tener un bucle anidado.

Comment: Primero queria agradecerte mucho la respuesta, estuve durante el dia testeando mucho esto y logre llegar mas o menos a una solucion pero me surgio una duda, tratando de hacer un arreglo de mayor tamaño (no mucho mas, solo 19) tengo problemas de leak de memoria segun entiendo, por que puede ser?
Adjunto foto de lo que me aparece, primero pense que podia ser el editor online por lo que trate en un IDE dedicado de mi maquina y recibo el mismo error.
https://ibb.co/YX64M63
  A mi codigo le pasa lo mismo aunque lo hice un poco distinto. (notar error en el resultado)

Comment: Comento que en mi codigo logre solucionar este error, pero en el que me propusiste no pude, voy a editar mi pregunta inicial con una respuesta actualizada de como logre hacerlo andar. Gracias !